# Different ways to specify libraries to gcc/g++

Tags: gcc, g++, linker, libraries

I'd be curious to understand if there's any substantial difference in specifying libraries (both shared and static) to gcc/g++ in the two following ways (CC can be g++ or gcc)

```
CC -o output_executable /path/to/my/libstatic.a /path/to/my/libshared.so source1.cpp source2.cpp ... sourceN.cpp
```

vs

```
CC -o output_executable -L/path/to/my/libs -lstatic -lshared source1.cpp source2.cpp ... sourceN.cpp
```

I can only see a major difference being that passing directly the fully-specified library name would make for a greater control in choosing static or dynamic versions, but I suspect there's something else going on that can have side effects on how the executable is built or will behave at runtime, am I right?

Andrea.

Comment: Have you tried both and compared the resulting executable files?

Comment: Not really. Might be my next test, even though I'd prefer to see if there's some "official" information about this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I can answer myself basing on some experiments and a deeper reading of gcc documentation:

From gcc documentation: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html

> [...] The linker handles an archive file by scanning through it for members which define symbols that have so far been referenced but not defined. But if the file that is found is an ordinary object file, it is linked in the usual fashion. The only difference between using an -l option and specifying a file name is that -l surrounds library  with `lib' and`.a' and searches several directories

This actually answers also to the related doubt about the 3rd option of directly specifying object files on the gcc command line (i.e. in that case all the code in the object files will become part of the final executable, while using archives, only the object files that are really needed will be pulled in).

Comment: when using full path to .so - what happens during runtime on a different environment? how is the .so being looked-up? it seems that its' searching for the entire string as a library, hence if it doesn't exist within the original exact location in the target environment - it can't be found.. how to overcome that?

Comment: What normally happens, if the .so has a "soname" (i.e. the library name with the addition of a major version number), is that the "soname" is registered as a dependency in the executable. Then when starting the executable the runtime linker (usually /lib/ld-linux.so.X on linux) will look in the various locations (determined by the platform, the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable and potentially the rpath argument used during building) for the soname (which usually on the filesystem is a symlink to the .so real name). See also http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html

Comment: thanks! Discovered soname and rpath myself few hours ago :)